# Excel VBA Vlookup different workbook without the the file opened

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a macro with Excle VBA that Vlookup a different workbook without opening the file, however, the system highlighted the "'" before C:,and showed Compile error "Expected: expression". I am trying get this done without using it in a string "=Vlookup .... etc"."

```
For j = 2 To lastRow
With Worksheets("ABC")
.Range("K" & j).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range("B" & j),'C:\Sales\John''s file\[Sales.xlsx]Weekly'!$A:$C,3,1)
Next j
```

Comment: You can't do it using `VLookup` without opening the file or using a formula string.

Comment: i think something like this would work: `ExecuteExcel4Macro("vlookup(R" & j & "C2,'C:\Sales\John''s file\[Sales.xlsx]Weekly'!C1:C3,3,1)")`

Answer (score 0):

'C:\Sales\John''s file[Sales.xlsx]Weekly'!$A:$C needs to be in double quotes as it is a string you are passing in also you probably only want a single quote on `john''s`